# Invalid arguments for execv function call

Tags: c, execv

An example of what the program should do:

```
./executable ls -l
```

should do the same as

```
ls -l
```

so basically it's a useless interpreter for shell commands.

I've created a string `fullpath` that contains `/bin/commandname` and a two dimensional array `arguments`, which is basically `argv` but without the first two entries (which are `executable` and `commandname`).

For the `./executable ls -l` example it actually returns the following:

```
full path: /bin/ls
Argument 0: -l
```

which is correct, but `execv` does literally nothing.

How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    char path[6] = "/bin/";
    char* fullpath = (char*)malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(argv[1]));
    strcat(fullpath, path);
    strcat(fullpath, argv[1]);
    printf("full path: %s\n", fullpath);

    char *arguments[argc-1];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc-2; i++){
        arguments[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[i+2]));
        strcpy(arguments[i], argv[i+2]);
        printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, argv[i+2]);
    }

    execv("/bin/ls", arguments);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program seems functional when we modify the following line :

```
char *arguments[argc-1];
```

Your char **arguments have to be like this line :

`char *arguments[] = { "/bin/ls", "-l", NULL };`

In other words, don't forget to indicate the command first; and be sure to put NULL at the end of your char **.

Good luck ! ;)

Comment: But what if there are more than just one argument?

Comment: You receive your command following by its options, right ?

Argv is a variable with the type char **; and you need a char ** to save the options of the command.

Comment: If argv[1] is your command and if the others parameters are the options of the command; you can modify the address pointed by argv to retrieve only what you want to take. In my exemple, You have to do :

argv = argv + 2;

With this modification, the pointer argv should point on your first option.
The char **argv already contains a "NULL" value at the end of the array; so you can send argv to execve as the options.
It's obvious, but if you want to access at the command (argv[1] at the beginning), you can change the address pointed by argv :

argv = argv - 1;